# merge queries to fastest answer

Tags: mysql

i have to show status of system to end user:
so i have a set of query that show sent data in 1min,5min,hour,day,month intervals

```
$sentCount = new stdClass();
$sentCount->amon = $link->query("select * from row_sent where result='succes' and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, send_date , now()) < 2073600 ;")->num_rows;
$sentCount->amin = $link->query("select * from row_sent where result='succes' and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, send_date , now()) < 60 ;")->num_rows;
$sentCount->a5min = $link->query("select * from row_sent where result='succes' and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, send_date , now()) < 300 ;")->num_rows;
$sentCount->ahour = $link->query("select * from row_sent where result='succes' and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, send_date , now()) < 3600 ;")->num_rows;
$sentCount->aday = $link->query("select * from row_sent where result='succes' and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, send_date , now()) < 86400 ;")->num_rows;
```

but this style of code need a large time to excute
how can i change it to get faster answer !?

Comment: dont do `select *`. get only relevant columns you need

Comment: you need rows count? than use `COUNT(*)` function in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need only Row counts. Issues with your current code are following:

- If you just want to get the number of rows, you should use inbuilt [COUNT()](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count/) function. It will be much faster.
- Secondly, your data packet from Database server to Application code becomes much smaller now. You are not fetching all the row data, instead just a number is coming now.
- Also, read [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Try the following query:

```
$sentCount = new stdClass();
$sentCount->amon = $link->query("select COUNT(*) as count from row_sent where result='succes' and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, send_date , now()) < 2073600 ;")->row['count'];
$sentCount->amin = $link->query("select COUNT(*) as count from row_sent where result='succes' and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, send_date , now()) < 60 ;")->row['count'];
$sentCount->a5min = $link->query("select COUNT(*) as count from row_sent where result='succes' and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, send_date , now()) < 300 ;")->row['count'];
$sentCount->ahour = $link->query("select COUNT(*) as count from row_sent where result='succes' and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, send_date , now()) < 3600 ;")->row['count'];
$sentCount->aday = $link->query("select COUNT(*) as count from row_sent where result='succes' and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, send_date , now()) < 86400 ;")->row['count'];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of you can combine into one query and use `IF` and `SUM` to get a result.

```
SELECT
    *,
    SUM(IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, send_date, NOW()) < 2073600,1,0)) AS MONTH,
    SUM(IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, send_date, NOW()) < 60,1,0)) AS one_min,
    SUM(IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, send_date, NOW()) < 300,1,0)) AS five_min,
    SUM(IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, send_date, NOW()) < 3600,1,0)) AS HOUR,
    SUM(IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, send_date, NOW()) < 86400,1,0)) AS DAY
    FROM
        row_sent
    WHERE
        result = 'succes';
```